# creating DTO object in one class and processing the DTO object in another object using ExecuterService

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a DTO class in one class and to process the DTO class in another thread. But the coding I created below creates all the DTO and then only I am able to get the `List<DTO>` as a whole, not as a single DTO.

```
public class Executer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        Set<Callable<List<EmpDTO>>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<List<EmpDTO>>>();

        callables.add(new Callable<List<EmpDTO>>() {
            public List<EmpDTO> call() throws Exception {
                List<EmpDTO> empDTO=new ArrayList<EmpDTO>();
                for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
                    EmpDTO emp = new EmpDTO();
                    emp.name ="name";
                    emp.employeeId=i;
                    emp.age="27";
                    empDTO.add(emp);
                    System.out.println("added "+i);
                }

                return empDTO;
            }
        });

        List<Future<List<EmpDTO>>> futures = service.invokeAll(callables);

        for(Future<List<EmpDTO>> future : futures){
            System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
        }





    }

}
```

What should I change in the code to create a DTO and to process the DTO while the another DTO is created parallel using `ExecutorService`?

Comment: I'm really not clear on what you want to achieve. This whole code would be much simpler and faster if it was basic, sequential code anyway. Creating 100 objects in memory is faster than crating a thread pool.

Comment: I am doing just a sample but the real time scenario will be thousands and lakhs and the DTO object will also be big. so just want to check it with simple logic

Comment: Even then, it will probably be faster (and simpler) with sequential code. But anyway, that doesn't answer my question: what do you want to achieve? What is the DTO that you want to create in the main thread (you're not creating any DTO in the main thread right now), and what should be the processing done in another thread?

Comment: Move your for-loop up one level, so that you create many Callables of EmpDto and not one Callable of List of EmpDTO. Also you might want to use CompletionService to receive the objects in the order the objects are constructed.